# Same USQL job taking almost 4 hours which was taking 30 minutes before why?

Tags: u-sql

I am having one ADF pipeline which runs USQL jobs with 1 AU. Its scheduled for daily once. normally it was taking around 30 minutes to complete the job. But now days I can see that jobs are taking more than 3 - 4 hours to completed the job. I can see that now days it is allocating more vertices to the job. So to compare I ran same old job. You can see below differences.

1) first Job -
https://cmndatadevdl01.azuredatalakeanalytics.net/jobLink/a3071c07-4b90-4f17-8dab-ba16764d9165
It is running with 5815 vertices with 1 AUs and completes in 28 minutes

2) second job -
https://cmndatadevdl01.azuredatalakeanalytics.net/Jobs/07e41502-3785-4f87-97d0-7682d544864b?api-version=2015-10-01-preview
I am running same above job with 5 AUS to save my time which completes in 46 minutes. I am running same code but it is using 42,330 vertices why?

3) third job
https://cmndatadevdl01.azuredatalakeanalytics.net/jobLink/c0037de7-6ba4-4aa5-9938-c7ba17b5edeb
This is almost same job but little different input but it takes 42173 vertices and complete in 4.4 hours with 1 AUs

I think there is something wrong with Azure data lake analytics account now days. I am facing this issue from couple of days. Around one week before everything was working fine. Please help  me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, we do not have access to your job links.

The number of vertices depends among other things primarily on the number of files, their size and - if you use tables - the number of distributions, partitions, and - often overlooked but very important - the number of table fragment that you may have generated while inserting into the tables.

Can you tell us more about your data?

1. Are you querying files? What format (e.g., JSON, CSV etc)? Did they grow in number or size?
2. Are you querying tables? Are you inserting into them frequently? When did you last rebuild the table or table partition?